# Separate the fetch data from core data in different UITableView's sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

Say I have:date, food, amount  attributes in my "Record" entity

I fetch the data from my db (core data), I've set the predicate to only fetch the data to specific month.

How can I display them in UITableView like the following:

---July 1----

cell

cell

---July 2----

cell

cell

cell

Comment: can you elaborate your question???

Comment: Have a look at he ["DateSectionTitles"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute is of type `NSDate` so every date will be unique and result in a separate section. This is clearly not desired.

You need to follow the example in the Apple Sample code [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html). Essentially, you create a transient string object with your managed object subclass that represents the date. You can then use that attribute as the `sectionNameKeyPath` of your fetched results controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"YOUR SECTION KeyPath"
                                               cacheName:nil];
```

Just fill in the name of the attribute containing the date for the sectionNameKeyPath.

Comment: You need to add that fetchRequest must be sorted by `sectionNameKeyPath` path to your answer.